# How can I add displacement to part of a material in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I made a mixed texture on cycles, that has a image texture as color, and a layer weight for the 'border' effects. Now I want to use the same image as bump, but I want to know the correct configuration/node order to do that.

[image]

Comment: Connect your texture to the displacement socket in the output node

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have a good control over a bump value add to your existing nodes set a *Mix RGB* node (Add--> Color-->Mix RGB), set its type to *Multiply* and the *Color 1* to pure white. Connect it to other ones as shown below.
[image]

Now changing a factor of the node  will result in a different amount of bumpiness.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use an image texture to influence the *Normal* value on any standard shader like as shown:

[image]
[image]

You can also plug the image texture directly into the *Displace* value of your *Output* shader:

[image]
[image]

The results are almost identical for both of the methods, however using the Displace method means you must mix the colors of all the textures you want to have influence the bumpiness of the material.

Also notice that you can use a *Math* node to influence the strength of the displacement (the bump value uses the *Strength* value). Set your *Math* node to *Multiply* and change the *Value* as desired:

[image]
[image]

Now the bumpiness is diminished noticeably. You can also increase the *Value* setting to increase the bumpiness.

Comment: The bump node is a good way to go since it allows normal maps and image based bumped mapping at the same time.  The Displacement socket on the Material Output Node cannot currently be used in combination with normal maps.